# How to hide Typescript files in browser?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an app with Typescript, Angular2 and Ionic2. Now when I am running the file in de browser, I can see all the source code from the .ts files..

Does anybody knows how to hide this? See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "sourceMap": false,
        ...
    }
```

If you disable source maps, your typescript will no longer be loaded from the map files. But to completly "hide" them, you can remove them once you push your code in production, since typescript is absolutly not needed for your application to work once it's transpilled to JS.

Also, keep in mind that Typescript is transpilled to JS which is still client-side code, and it will be readable by the client. If you want to obfuscate your code, you should take a look at [webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) (which is used by angular-cli)

Comment: Hi @Supamiu, yeah its working but still I can see my .ts files and typescript code in a contextual manner. Even function names and variable names are also visible. How can i hide those? Thanking You!

Answer (score 4):

You can see the original source code because you're emitting sourcemaps.

Sourcemaps are used by the browser to link you're JavaScript files to your TypeScript.

What you can do is disable sourcemap generation on your `tsconfig.json` when you're compiling to production. Besides this, you could also use the `outDir` property to compile all your app into a `dist` folder. This should be the folder you deploy to production, not your `src` folder.

There are another good reasons to use a different output folder, for example ignoring it on your git repository.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this post](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod)

> Uglification: rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.

Hence, adding the `--prod` flag solved the issue:

```
ng build --env=prod --prod
```

the generated `dist` folder is running on the [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server)

and the result:

[image: ng build --env=prod --prod]